# Установка запрета скачивания файлов с определенного домена

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет.

Вопрос на миллион.. ) Есть 2 подкаталога /domain1 и /domain2, находящиеся в каталоге /userfile (т.е. окончательные пути с рутовой директории до этих каталогов - /userfile/domain1 и /userfile/domain2). И к одному серверу привязано два домена domain1.com и domain2.com. Задача состоит в том, что нужно с помощью только одного htaccess'а без использования php скриптов и т.п. РАЗРЕШИТЬ скачивание всех файлов, находящихся внутри каталока /domain1 для пользователей зашедших на сервер с домена domain1.com и запретить с других. То же самое нужно проделать и для каталога /domain2 с домена domain2.com соответственно.

Вот такой файлик у меня получился (он лежит в каталоге /userfile/domain1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /userfile/domain1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^domain1\.com$
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /$1 [F]
```

Но почему-то 403 ошибка (флаг F) вылетает всегда, независимо от того с какого домена я зайду. Где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domain1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  domain2
RewriteRule .* /access_denied.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domain2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  domain1
RewriteRule .* /access_denied.html
```

Как вариант